# enqueuing a minified CSS into Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I am currently using a style.css with a wordpress theme (obviously) and when I am editing it I am also minifying the file on save. Which generates another file as style.min.css,

Now, I already have the style.css enqueued in the functions.php file but do I need to swap it out for the .min.css?

Or will it automatically load the .min.css file instead? (thus making it load a little faster using the minified file).

Thanks,
Az

Comment: no, you need to do it manually, there is no automatic process of swapping

Comment: are you getting your updated css in style.css?. 
If yes then no need to add min.css, if not then you have to enqueue it separately.

Answer (score 0):

style.css is a required file for WP as functions.php. No can swap. Whatever you are using to minify (SASS or task runners) needs to output to style.css. Just remember to add "!" to the style comments so that they are not minified. i.e

```
/*!
Theme Name: theme_name
Theme URI: http://theme_name.com/
Author: theme_name
Author URI: http://theme_name.com/
Description: WordPress Theme for theme_name
*/
```

Or you can simple enqueue that min.css file to the functions.php file and leave style.css with the comment section only with no css code.

```
function new_theme_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style ( 

    wp_enqueue_style ( 'text-domain-new-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_theme_scripts' );
```